# Finite subgroups of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and $\mathrm{SO}(3)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to understand the proof 2.6.7 in "Joseph A. Wolf - Spaces of Constant Curvature" page 88.

This shows that every finite subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is either Cyclic or Binary where the binary groups are defined to be the preimage under the double cover $\pi: \mathrm{SU}(2) \rightarrow \mathrm{SO}(3)$ of the finite subgroups of $\mathrm{SO}(3): G^*= \pi^{-1} (H)$ (using random finite subgroups letters).

Define $U \leq \mathrm{SU}(2)$ finite and $O=\pi(U)$. He splits the two cases $U\neq \pi^{-1}(O)$ and $U=\pi^{-1}(O)$.

In the first case he deduce without proof that $\pi: U \simeq O$ and $$\pi^{-1}(O) = U \times \{ \pm 1 \} $$ Where clearly $\{ \pm 1 \} $ is the center of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and is what we use to define $\mathrm{SO}(3) = \mathrm{SU}(2)/ \{ \pm 1 \} $. Can someone help me? I tried to see it, but I definetly don't.

Comment: "Clearly the center of $SU(2)$ is $\{\pm 1\}$". Yes, see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686557/how-to-compute-the-center-of-su2). For the finite subgroups, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40351/what-are-the-finite-subgroups-of-su-2c), for example. It has some more details.

Comment: For the center was just a clarification and not a question, but thanks for the other link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $-1 \in U$ then $\ker \pi = \{ \pm 1 \} \le U$ and so $U = \pi^{-1}(\pi(U)) = \pi^{-1}(O)$. So if $U \ne \pi^{-1}(O)$ then $-1 \not\in U$ and so $ U \cap \{\pm 1\} = \{1\}$, so $U \times \{\pm 1\} \le {\rm SU}(2)$.

Clearly $\pi(U \times \{\pm 1\}) = \pi(U) = O$, so $ \pi^{-1}(O)  = U \times \{\pm 1\}$. To see this, note that clearly $U \times \{\pm 1\} \le \pi^{-1}(O)$ and, if $g \in \pi^{-1}(O)$, then there exists $h \in U$ with $\pi(g) = \pi(h)$, so $gh^{-1} \in \ker \pi = \{ \pm 1\}$ and $g \in 
U \times \{\pm 1\}$.

Also, but the First Isomorphism Theorem, $U \cong (U \times \{\pm 1\})/\{\pm 1\} \cong \pi(U)=O$.

Comment: I don't get something.
1) How do you prove that if $U \neq  \pi^{-1} (O)$ implies $-1 \notin U$?
I can use the First isomorphism theorem to show $U\simeq O$ and I see $\{ \pm 1 \} \subset \pi^{-1}(O)$. Then we see that $\pi: SU(2) \rightarrow SU(2)/ \{\pm 1 \}$ so it quotient out $\{ \pm 1 \}$ from $SU(2)$ and if $O\simeq U$, $-1 \notin U$ since $1$ always is? I'm not sure about this argument.
2) Why $\pi (U \times \{ \pm 1 \}) = \pi (U) = O$ implies $\pi^{-1}(O) = U times \{ \pm 1 \}$? If I can just apply $\pi^{-1}$ I would have $\pi^{-1}(O) = U$. I don't understand.
I really thank you.

Comment: I've added a bit more detail, but all of these things follow easily from $\ker \pi = \{ \pm1 \}$.